# cleaning up glitched complex overlapping mesh architecture

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, collision, photogrammetry

I am relatively new to Blender (Rhino for now) and tried to collide multiple 3d photogrammetry models. In the end, I glitched it my resizing the meshes to create an unexpected architectural model. The issue (obviously) is now that I got many unwanted overlaps etc. on the inside which I don´t want as there should be open and "big" spaces/rooms inside the model. I am just trying to figure out if there is a possibility to clean that mesh/mess up or if there is basically no chance. Any help would be appreciated.

cheers

[image]
[image]
[image]